# How do I login to my website in safari from its app?

Tags: php, ios, codeigniter, authentication

I'm making an iPhone app for a startup that will accept payments for charity. Due to apple's [payment guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#payments), I need to make the website open in Safari to make the payment.

To do this (due to the way the website was made) the user needs to be logged in to the website. I was wondering if there was a good way to make the website log in by just pressing a button in the app. I think I've seen this with Facebook on Android, I haven't seen it in any iOS apps yet.

A bit of info about the website:

- It's built using PHP using the [CodeIgniter framework](http://www.codeigniter.com).
- I'm currently an intern here, and they outsourced the website work to a different company, so no one here really knows much about the website's coding.
- The company that built the website is very busy with adding features being requested by the startup.
- I don't know PHP, but I did have to create the API (I used [this library](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver)) since there wasn't an existing one in place. Due to this, while I have some understanding of PHP, it is very limited

Currently the only thought I've had is passing a URL that contains the username and password hash in it to log in to the website and making a page that takes that info and logs you in. Obviously this is ridiculously insecure and probably not a good idea. Can I open the login page in the app and have it remembered by Safari? Or is there a good way to redirect to the website (in Safari), have the user login, and then automatically redirect back to the app? Again, no PHP experience so apologies if that last question is a bit stupid.

Is there a way to do this, and if so, what is the best way to go about it?

Thanks!

Comment: can't you open browser inside your app ?

Comment: Please read the first two sentences of the question again

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform a login in Safari from your app.

You can open Safari with the login URL:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"http://yoursite.com/site")!)
```

You can also automatically redirect back to the app after logging in, using URL schemes. This requires server code to be changed. There's a tutorial by Twitter [here](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/mobile/url-schemes).